# Drawing "higher-level" object

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm using SFML for a Computer Science project - making a chess game. I have a class `Square` which is a single square of the chessboard - currently, it contains four vertices (four `sf::Vertex` objects in a member variable `sf::VertexArray`) and is colored either white or black. A class `ChessBoard` encapsulates a `std::vector` of Squares.

Using the tutorial given by SFML, I'm able to draw a single square. However, the `draw()` function works based on vertices, and since the `ChessBoard` class doesn't not actually contain vertices, but rather objects that themselves contain vertices, I'm not able to draw the chess board (i.e. its internal `draw()` function does not work).

Does anyone know how to work around this?
(I can provide more info/clarification/code if necessary/helpful.)

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how "higher level drawing" is supposed to work.

Your parent class(es) shouldn't have to bother how to draw children. You're mixing responsibilities.

Instead, subclass [`sf::Drawable`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) (and `sf::Transformable`, if required).

All this does is forcing you to implement a `draw()` member, which does all the drawing.

Here's a simple example for your `ChessBoard` class:

```
class ChessBoard : public sf::Drawable {

    void draw (RenderTarget &target, RenderStates states) const {
        for (auto &tile : mTiles) // Iterate over all board pieces
            target.draw(tile, states); // Draw them
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is trivial to setup. In a similar way, you can overload your `Square` class. (Isn't that name too generic? Why not simply reusing `sf::RectangleShape`?)

```
class ChessBoard : public sf::Drawable {

    void draw (RenderTarget &target, RenderStates states) const {
        target.draw(mVertices, states);
    }
}
```

So, back to your main game loop. How to draw the `ChessBoard`? Again, trivial:

```
while (window.isOpen()) {
    // All the other things happening

    window.draw(mChessBoard);
}
```

While the advantages of this approach might not be as obvious at first, it's pretty easy to see that you're capable of passing responsibilities down the line. For example, the `ChessBoard` doesn't have to know how to properly draw a `Square`. In a trivial example – using unicolored polygons only – it's not that easy to notice, but your code will be a lot cleaner once you start adding shaders, textures, etc. Suddenly you'd no longer just have to return a `sf::VertexArray`, but you'll also need pointers or references to the other ressources. So the `ChessBoard` would have to know, which components to request from `Square` to draw it properly (Does it have a shader? Do I need a texture?).

Comment: Thanks very much for all the information. Will have to look through in detail later, as am on a crunch to finish my project, but very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Silly me. Implemented a getter inside class `Square` that returned the vertex array, & inside `Chessboard` looped through the vector of squares, calling the getter on each iteration.